# What happens when you explicitly link a library that has already been implicitly linked?

Tags: c++, dll, linker

If foo.dll has been implicitly linked at compile time but is loaded again via LoadLibrary at runtime does the application get a new instance of foo.dll or is it the same instance from when it was implicitly loaded with the executable?

Comment: Shared library only be loaded in memory once, so it is the same instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LoadLibrary Will return the same instance handle and do nothing;

[LoadLibrary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya)

> The system maintains a per-process reference count on all loaded
>   modules. Calling LoadLibrary increments the reference count. Calling
>   the FreeLibrary or FreeLibraryAndExitThread function decrements the
>   reference count. The system unloads a module when its reference count
>   reaches zero or when the process terminates (regardless of the
>   reference count).
>
> If the specified module is a DLL that is not already loaded for the
>   calling process, the system calls the DLL's DllMain function with the
>   DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH value.

Comment: What are you quoting?